# What is it that birds dream of?

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme

> For as long as I can remember, I've had this dream.
> Let me reassure you, it's a dream many have seen.
>
> I rise above this terrestrial sphere onto a higher plane.
> Given this incredible power, I break out of my chains.
>
> How far will I be able to travel? Only my mind limits me.
> To have bestowed upon me this incredible gift, a hero I'll be.

What is my dream?

Comment: [PalomaBlanca][1]

  [1]: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zl0KCW-l_rI

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Edit (note, I looked at hexomino and QuantumTwinkie's answers, they both, along with the comment's throughout, helped a lot.  Go up vote them :-)):

It's:

> Space Flight

For as long as I can remember, I've had this dream.
Let me reassure you, it's a dream many have seen.

> People dream of flying through space (movies and shows have been made about the dream).

I rise above this terrestrial sphere onto a higher plane.
Given this incredible power, I break out of my chains.

> Break the chains of being stuck on Earth

How far will I be able to travel? Only my mind limits me.
To have bestowed upon me this incredible gift, a hero I'll be.

> You have a vast, unexplored area to explore

Bonus:

> The title -> Bird's are limited by Earth, they may dream of flying through space
> Acrostic -> fly through space

Original Guess:

> Superman

Comment: Not a bad guess, but the answer isn't a person.

Comment: @Joe-You-Know is it just ROT13(fcnpr-syvtug)?

Comment: You've got it! That's what I was looking for. Although Wikipedia lists it without the hyphen.

Comment: @Joe-You-Know yay! Edited!

Comment: Great edit! You really got what I was looking for.

Comment: @Joe-You-Know so this is the correct answer?

Comment: Yes it is. If you're worried about being accepted as the correct answer, I always wait 24 hours before doing so.

Comment: @Joe-You-Know ahh! I did not know that :-)

Answer (score 8):

**Edit:** Given OP's comment on my answer, I think the answer may be

> Rocket

Original answer

> Space (or perhaps Outer Space)

A lot of the reasoning remains the same.

Acrostic

> Spells FLIGHT

Title

> It would be even above what a bird could reach so may be what they dream of

For as long as I can remember, I've had this dream. 
Let me reassure you, it's a dream many have seen.

> Many people have dreamed of becoming astronauts

I rise above this terrestrial sphere onto a higher plane. 
Given this incredible power, I break out of my chains.

> Reaching into outer space would break free from the atmosphere (terrestrial sphere)

How far will I be able to travel? Only my mind limits me.

> Space is very large, possibly infinite.

To have bestowed upon me this incredible gift, a hero I'll be.

> Astronauts are lauded as heroes, think the moon landing. 
>  Also *Rocketman*, the famous Elton John song.

Comment: Your line of reasoning is right (for this is what limits birds). However, the answer is how they move through your answer. So, you're really close.

Comment: I've edited the answer now, not sure if this is what you're looking for.

Comment: This is more the object that can provide the answer. (You're super close). Wikipedia has a page dedicated to it. I told QuantumTwinkie that his original answer was part of the answer.

Answer (score 4):

Are you

> Wings

For as long as I can remember, I've had this dream.

> You need wings to fly.

Let me reassure you, it's a dream many have seen

> People have tried.

I rise above this terrestrial sphere onto a higher plane.

> In a higher "Plane"!

Given this incredible power, I break out of my chains.

> People have never flown themselves

How far will I be able to travel? Only my mind limits me.

> Mars? Maybe Kepler-186f?

To have bestowed upon me this incredible gift, a hero I'll be.

> Bird-man

Acrostic

> Flight

Title

> Birds have wings to fly.

Comment: It's most certainly part of the answer. But I'm looking for something even more liberating than this (or more accurately, it's an even greater form of travel)

Comment: No, your first answer is much closer (or that is to say it's a form of movement). The title you can take literally. What is it that birds dream of if they can already fly?

Comment: A nice edit, but not what I was looking for.

Comment: That's the closest you've gotten so far.

Comment: You can theoretically achieve the answer by using either of those.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's

> flying

because

> it's a common dream

and

> it involves physical rising from the terrestrial plane (the ground) into the sky

and

> superheroes & birds both fly

Answer (score 1):

Is it

> FLIGHT

It fits the clue, and it is an

> acrostic

of the question.

Answer (score 1):

Already reasonable answers are provided, however, here are my two cents-

> It's *vertical take off/ landing*

As,

> birds need a run based take off to flight or land. However, feature like *vertical take off or landing* , hence could be a cause of their dream ( or rather jealous of/ envy with)

Comment: This is a great answer too.